# For loop output in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple program creating a cluster of k-neighbours for some example data in C++. So far I'm by the first iteration of the algorythm. Would someone explain why do I have so strange output of the `string point[] = {...}` array? I expect just letters like {A B C D .. H}, but instead  have output like this:

```
A C2 2
4B C1 2.23607
9C C1 2.82843
17D C1 3.60555
30E C2 1
31F C1 2.23607
36G C2 0
36H C1 0
36
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.031 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Where do the numbers before Letters come from?

And here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char point[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};
float x[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 2};
float y[] = {3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1};
float m1[] = {x[(sizeof(x)/sizeof(float))-1], y[(sizeof(y)/sizeof(float))-1]};
float m2[] = {x[(sizeof(x)/sizeof(float))-2], y[(sizeof(y)/sizeof(float))-2]};
string group[8];
float sumdq =0;

    for(int i=0;i<=sizeof(point)-1;i++)
    {
        float d1 = sqrt(pow(x[i]-m1[0],2) + pow(y[i]-m1[1],2));
        float d2 = sqrt(pow(x[i]-m2[0],2) + pow(y[i]-m2[1],2));
        if(d1<d2)
        {
            group[i] = "C1";
            sumdq =sumdq + pow(d1,2);
            cout<<point[i]<< " "<<group[i]<< " "<<d1<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            group[i] = "C2";
            sumdq =sumdq + pow(d2,2);
            cout<<point[i]<< " "<<group[i]<< " "<<d2<<endl;
        }
        cout<<sumdq;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are shoving a lot of stuff into `cout`, so the program is consequently printing a lot of stuff.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` which tells you the [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) without having to do ridiculous `sizeof()` math.

Comment: I don't see any `string point [] = ...` anywhere in your code

Comment: `cout<<sumdq;` prints a number that you see in the beginning of each line starting from the 2nd.

Comment: @tadman `std::size` also works here. Actually `sizeof` is never needed to get the size of an arary. Either `std::size` works or `sizeof` is wrong as well (because its a pointer not an array, and then `std::size` will nicely fail to compile)

Comment: maybe you want to remove the current `endl`s and instead place it here `cout<<sumdq << endl;`

Comment: IMHO, you should create a `struct` that models an input line.  Add an overloaded `operator>>` to read data into the struct members.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I get it. I,ve put `cout<<` inside the loop, and that was the problem. Thank you  *463035818_is_not_a_number*. And thanks *tadman* for hint with `std::vector`. BTW, is the only option to show size of an array? isn't there anything like `x.length()` in Python?

Anyway thak you alot for answares

Comment: Arrays are created at compile time.  Create a macro or constexpr for the capacity and place into a header file.  Include the header file as necessary when you need to know the capacity.

Comment: there is `std::size`. `std::size(x)` is the size of `x`

Comment: Thank you. I gonna try this